# Is it possible to throw a stick without giving it a rotational motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

When walking with our dog I always throw wooden sticks for her. Then one time I wondered if I could throw the stick (normaly, so not like a spear) without imparting on it a rotational motion around its centre of mass. I didn´t succeed. Is it possible?

Comment: Step 1: Hold the stick by the center of mass. Step 2: Throw straight.

Comment: You really shouldn't throw sticks for your dog, [here's why](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2016/jan/20/dont-throw-sticks-for-your-dogs-to-fetch-vets).

Comment: My dog never has problems with it! And by throwing the stick I mean throwing it while holding it on one of the ends (holding it in the middle is about the same as a throwing a spear).

Comment: javelin: apply the force in the same direction as its most symmetric moment of interia

Comment: This would be the easiest in a vacuum. Although you can throw a stick without giving it rotational momentum, air friction makes the stick slightly align with its trajectory. Your best bet would be to A) throw the stick in a vacuum B) throw the stick straight up C) throw the stick straight down

Answer (score 2):

1. Hold it in the center, make it vertical and either throw it, or give yourself some spin and just release it. If you hold it in the center and keep it horizontal, it will be like a spear, but if you hold it in the center vertically, it will also go without rotation.
2. Hold with both the hands and throw like a a two hand hi-five.
3. Throw like a javelin or spear, or an arrow.
4. If you must hold it at one edge, then hold the stick with one grip tightly and throw it in perpendicular direction to its length, without twisting your wrist. Kind of the way tennis players hit volleys.

Comment: I was talking about the case that you hold the stick at one of the two edges (number 4). I can imagine the last example you give, but what if I throw the stick like every stick thrower does, like a baseball player throws the ball? From the back to the front, and I let the stick go at an angle of about 45 degrees. Can´t you (in theory, because I couldn´t do it in practice), use the movement of your wrist to counter the rotation?

Comment: OK, the idea is to throw the stick in such a way that two ends are moving at same speed, and in same direction. That throw is not possible in the way you described. However to realize it, you have to make it a "throw, and adjust". Means throw the stick any way and follow up with your hand to stop the spin by pushing the closer end so its speed and direction match the farther edge. Will be extremely hard if not impossible.